# Sequence of learning web languages

Tags: java, api, dynamic

I am currently learning Java, and have access to a slew of books from OReilly.
I was wondering what kind of languages should I pursue, in hopes of making a dynamic, service-based, social network integrated website. (I would like top include APIs from google, twitter, facebook etc.). I would guess HTML, CSS, PHP, MySQL, Ajax(?).

Please advise on the Order in which these languages should be learned (HTML

Just to give you an idea of where i'm at, I am doing GUIs in java.

Thank you

Comment: html, css, and mysql aren't programming languages.

Comment: I would argue that with stored procedured, MySQL can now be considered a programming language as well... limited, but scriptable.

Comment: SQL is definitely a programming language; markup languages are debatable.  It's irrelevant to the spirit of the question, though: if you're making web pages, you need HTML and CSS.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The OP isn't claiming they are programming languages, just languages.  So you can quit your splitting hairs and focus on the question.

Comment: @Falmarri: Very true, but I think the sense of the question is clear. (And he didn't say **programming** languages. SQL is a query language, HTML is a markup language, CSS is...um...CSS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is pretty subjective, but I'll give you my 2 cents in a quick overview fashion. I'd go about it in this order:

- Continue with Java
- HTML/CSS
- JavaScript
- SQL and database backends
- PHP
- AJAX (which is applied PHP+Javascript+SQL)

**Continue with Java to get a good, strong background in a strongly-type, object oriented language.** I think this is essential. Web technologies like PHP and JavaScript do not enforce type-safety which can lead to bad programming habits. Once you start "seeing" programming in an object-oriented fashion, you will be able to apply it to other programming concepts.

Read up on HTML and CSS (concurrently) to get a good idea feel for how webpages are designed. Without this, you'll be lost!

Next you can move on to JavaScript. It'll be nice and familiar, if you have a good background in Java. Be sure to read up on closures and other modern JavaScript practices.

At that point, you'll want to learn how to drive a webpage through a database backend. So learn how to design relational databases and how to get data from and put data into them using SQL.

Next, you'll want to learn a server-side scripting language, such as PHP or Python. This will give you the tools you need to create webpages which access your database backend.

Once you know these technologies, and not before, you will be ready to dive into AJAX. Be mindful that this is more of a concept than a technology -- and more of a buzzword than a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Must learn client side tools:

- HTML
- CSS
- JavaScript

Then pick a server language. As some have pointed out the comments, Java has a huge range of libraries and it might be a good pick to run with PHP. It has a similar syntax so shouldn't be too much of a learning curve.

Or, if your comfortable using Java and don't mind the learning curve to adapting that knowledge to web generation than that is an option too.

Then pick a database - MySQL, PostGres or whatever you are comfortable with. Learn the SQL specific to that database.

Then learn about:

- Web Security frameworks
- ORM / MVC framworks for your chosen server language
- front side libraries like jQuery, etc.

(EDIT: amended according to the comments below)

Comment: +1, but *"If you using Java, stick with it."* I'd at least take a look at PHP. Java has a **massive** set of libraries of things you can do with it, but PHP has a massive set of prebuilt applications you can tailor. (He says, not having yet made time to really learn PHP properly. :) )

Comment: No, you are right, T.J.  PHP is a good server-side scripting language to get you up and running quickly.

Comment: Where would Perl fit in this sequence? or is Perl just like PHp

Answer (score 2):

You need to know HTML and CSS before you can even hope to do anything on the Web.  They're not programming languages, but they're the foundation of actual *web pages*, which any web application must eventually display.  After that, you can work on JavaScript, which is fundamentally a client-side language.  After *that*, you learn a server-side language of your choice; Ruby, Python, and PHP are the choices *du jour*, although any language will work, certainly including Java.  In conjunction with the server-side language, you will need to learn at least the basics of databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL, or what-have-you) and AJAX.

Don't get distracted by buzzwordism:  AJAX, for example, is just JavaScript interacting with your server-side language.

**Resources:**

- HTML, CSS, and JavaScript:  use the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). It is a complete and reliable reference.
- If you want to begin working with JavaScript before server-side programming, check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com).  Its utility will be limited without AJAX (which requires server-side scripting), but you can learn more about the DOM and begin to write dynamic web interfaces.
- Depending on which language you decide to use, you could choose a web framework:  Ruby, of course, has [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/); Python has [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonshq.com/pyramid/dev/).  Most people use PHP sans framework, but you can try something like [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/).  These frameworks basically bundle everything you need to produce a working web application into one overarching package, so that you don't need to worry about picking an ORM, picking a templating system, etc.
- You will want to learn SQL.  [sqlzoo](http://sqlzoo.net/) is a great site, and one that will give you a good grasp of the basics of a RDBMS.  After that, I recommend using [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org), but that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: Not entirely true about html and CSS. Yeah they're more than likely necessary, but there ARE widget based web design tools. see http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

Comment: It is true about HTML and CSS.  How do you know the widget based web design tool is generating good HTML and CSS unless you know what that looks like?  You have to know HTML and CSS yourself.

Comment: There are, but I would argue that you should understand the ideas underlying the widgets before you begin producing things with a widget library.  HTML/CSS have enough wrinkles (thinking about browser-compatibility, here) that eventually you're going to hit something that the widget library does stupidly--and if you can't work with the HTML/CSS directly, you're dead in the water.  Understanding the DOM is also necessary for any kind of UI coding you need to do... and it's easier to just learn it than to fob it off on a secondary library.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, just pointing out that there are abstractions to html and css

Comment: so would you recommend reading books on all these subjects or should I just use w3schools? If i start reading 20 pages a day + do code I can do 1 book in one month. Would this be a good ideea? I could even try to manage 40 pages.

Comment: Start out with w3schools.  It shouldn't take too long to pick up the basics of HTML and CSS... certainly less than a month.  You may need books when you get into learning a language (if you go that way).

Answer (score 0):

start with the HTML basics, HTML, CSS, Javascript then learn thebasics of PHP or ASP.NET, then learn the basics of some DQL like MySQL, MSSQL then go back and learn more advanced PHP. then get the handle of AJAX and pick up a JS API or two, jQuery, Prototype. then learn advanced DQL (MySQL, MSSQL stored procedures and such forth.) then go back and leanr everything that's changed in HTML in the intervening period. then pay someone who has been programming for at least 10 years to write your site for you. If you don't already have a real good basis in any given web language, you're not going to be able to learn enough fast enough to make the next facebook killer anyhow.

Comment: im not trying to make a facebook killer... maybe people misunderstood me. I am trying to make a web service that REVOLVES around facebook's users. I want to tightly integrate facebook in my website, as in fetching data, organising it, re-presenting it etc. for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

HTML
CSS
JS
then everything around JS like Ajax

Then PHP or ASP.NET whatever you prefer, and then SQL.